# Error trying to execute query in Elixir with Ecto

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I have an Elixir app that uses Ecto in order to execute queries in Postgres.
I have this Ecto schema:

```
defmodule Person do

  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "person" do
    field :name, :string
  end

end
```

I'm trying to make a simple select in Elixir:

```
query = from Person
result = Repo.all(query)
```

but after executing that code, I see this:

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.Connection.expr/3

The following arguments were given to Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.Connection.expr/3:

    # 1
    {{:., [], [{:&, [], [0]}, "name"]}, [], []}

    # 2
    {{[34, "Person", 34], [84 | "0"],
      Person}, []}

    # 3
    #Ecto.Query<from c0 in Person,
     select: c0>

Attempted function clauses (showing 10 out of 33):

    defp expr(-{:^, [], [ix]}-, _sources, _query)
    defp expr(-{{:., _, [{:parent_as, _, [as]}, field]}, _, []}-, _sources, query) when -is_atom(field)-
    defp expr({{:., _, [{:&, _, [idx]}, field]}, _, []}, sources, _query) when -is_atom(field)-
    defp expr(-{:&, _, [idx]}-, sources, _query)
    defp expr(-{:in, _, [_left, []]}-, _sources, _query)
    defp expr(-{:in, _, [left, right]}-, sources, query) when -is_list(right)-
    defp expr(-{:in, _, [left, {:^, _, [ix, _]}]}-, sources, query)
    defp expr(-{:in, _, [left, %Ecto.SubQuery{} = subquery]}-, sources, query)
    defp expr(-{:in, _, [left, right]}-, sources, query)
    defp expr(-{:is_nil, _, [arg]}-, sources, query)
    ...
    (23 clauses not shown)

(ecto_sql 3.7.2) lib/ecto/adapters/postgres/connection.ex:590: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.Connection.expr/3
(ecto_sql 3.7.2) lib/ecto/adapters/postgres/connection.ex:1284: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.Connection.intersperse_map/4
(ecto_sql 3.7.2) lib/ecto/adapters/postgres/connection.ex:340: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.Connection.select/3
(ecto_sql 3.7.2) lib/ecto/adapters/postgres/connection.ex:113: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.Connection.all/2
(ecto_sql 3.7.2) lib/ecto/adapters/postgres.ex:102: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.prepare/2
(ecto 3.7.2) lib/ecto/query/planner.ex:180: Ecto.Query.Planner.query_without_cache/4
(ecto 3.7.2) lib/ecto/query/planner.ex:150: Ecto.Query.Planner.query_prepare/6
(ecto 3.7.2) lib/ecto/query/planner.ex:125: Ecto.Query.Planner.query_with_cache/7
```

Also same result with Repo.all.

This are the versions that I'm using:
Elixir: 1.13
ecto_sql: 3.7.2
postgrex: 0.16.2

Does anyone has any idea what is making this error?

Thanks

Comment: `from p in Person`

Comment: @Aleksei Matiushkin I just tried your suggestion but same result

Comment: I meant you have to fulfil the query with this `p`, like: `from p in Person, select: p`. The latter would select all the records without filtering, for instance. https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#from/2

Comment: Perhaps [Elixir School - Ecto Query Basics](https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/ecto/querying_basics) can help you better grasp on how to query your Schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem:
I have a table in a Postgres database, that contains two fields:
person_age_123 and person_name_123.

So on my schema on Elixir, I was trying to map those database column names to a more "friendly" field names, like **age** and **name**.

So my Elixir schema was the following:

```
defmodule EctoApp.Person do

  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "person" do
    field :name, :string, [source: "person_name_123"]
    field :age, :integer, [source: "person_age_123"]
  end

end
```

and the error was because I was using " instead of :, so I think that the idea is to include atoms and not strings.

Anyway I thing that Elixir could show a more friendly message error, since I figure out the problem after try a lot of things.

Comment: I don't think Elixir/Phoenix needs a better error message.  The truth of the matter is that they don't actually know what's causing the error, so they spit out what part of the code failed.  It is then your job to figure out why that function override chain can't find any function with those parameters.

Comment: Plus, you should never have to explicitly reference columns like this, it's way too heavy-handed, maybe in some larger applications where things get tricky after years of development but not on a basic schema like this.  I'm thinking your migration names the columns differently than the schema, which is extra work that gives you nothing but errors like these ^.